# Decrease space between elements in React Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

As Newbie to React Native, I've got problems with putting three elements closer together.

In the picture of the application, you can see three buttons. They should be placed closer together while keeping the column.

[image]

Here is the code:

`App.js`, rendering the component `LandingPage`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import LandingPage from './src/screens/LandingPage/LandingPage'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <LandingPage></LandingPage>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
});
```

Component `LandingPage`, which uses the component `ButtonRounded`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import ButtonRounded from '../../components/ButtonRounded/ButtonRounded';

export default class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonPosition}>
          <ButtonRounded></ButtonRounded>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonPosition}>
          <ButtonRounded></ButtonRounded>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonPosition}>
          <ButtonRounded></ButtonRounded>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonPosition: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

And this is `ButtonRounded`component using NativeBase:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {Container, Header, Content, Button, Text} from 'native-base';

export default class ButtonRounded extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button rounded style={styles.button_style}>
        <Text style={styles.text_style}>Example</Text>
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button_style: {
    margin: '25%',
    backgroundColor: '#99D066',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text_style: {
    color: '#000',
  },
});
```

I've tried several ways to modify `flex` property, `padding` and `margin`. But somehow I feel that I'm missing something fundamental I just can't identify. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of my answer, is the full example.

React Native uses by default flexbox layout. I'll explain briefly 3 of the most used properties when using it. You'll need to play with `align-items`, `justify-content` and `flex-direction`.

#### `flex-direction`

establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container. Think of flex items as primarily laying out either in horizontal rows or vertical columns.

Main values are: `row`, `row-reverse`, `column`, `column-reverse`

#### `justify-content`

defines the alignment along the **main axis**. It helps distribute extra free space leftover when either all the flex items on a line are inflexible, or are flexible but have reached their maximum size. It also exerts some control over the alignment of items when they overflow the line.

Some of its most used values are:

- `flex-start` (default): items are packed toward the start of the flex-direction.
- `flex-end`: items are packed toward the end of the flex-direction.
- `center`: items are centered along the line
- `space-between`: items are evenly distributed in the line; first item is on the start line, last item on the end line
- `space-around`: items are evenly distributed in the line with equal space around them.
- `space-evenly`: items are distributed so that the spacing between any two items

#### `align-items`

defines the default behavior for how flex items are laid out along the **cross axis** on the current line. Think of it as the `justify-content` version for the cross axis (perpendicular to the main-axis).

Some of its most used values are:

- `stretch` (default): stretch to fill the container
- `flex-start`: items are placed at the start of the cross axis
- `flex-end`: items are placed at the end of the cross axis.
- `center`: items are centered in the cross-axis
  baseline: items are aligned such as their baselines align

To learn more flexbox, you can use an interactive and fun game for that called [flexboxfroggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) or read [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <LandingPage></LandingPage>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
});
```

```
export default class ButtonRounded extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button rounded style={styles.button_style}>
        <Text style={styles.text_style}>Example</Text>
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button_style: {
    backgroundColor: '#99D066',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  text_style: {
    color: '#000',
  },
});
```

```
export default class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonPosition}>
          <ButtonRounded></ButtonRounded>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonPosition}>
          <ButtonRounded></ButtonRounded>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonPosition}>
          <ButtonRounded></ButtonRounded>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: Playing around with these options doesn't give results ... layout just stays the same. The only time it changes at all is when `flex-end` is used on `justify-content` and `align-items`. Giving the container in `App.js` a fixed height seems to work better, but isn't this an ugly approach that should be avoided?

Comment: Remove `flex: 1,` from `buttonPosition`. Only parent element needs to have `flex`. Also remove your `margin: '25%',` from `button_style`

Comment: Wow this works! Ah, I see. Only parent needs `flex`. Thanks my friend

Comment: Just added a full example that also uses margin for more flexibility. Check the answer again.